# Node.js - execute the anonymous function that was passed to another function

Tags: node.js

I understand that Node.js has the concept of event-driven, asynchronous callbacks, by utilizing an event loop.

```
database.query("SELECT * FROM hugetable", function(rows) { var result = rows; });
console.log("Hello World");
```

Here, instead of expecting database.query() to directly return a result to us, we pass it a second parameter, an anonymous function.
Now, Node.js can handle the database request asynchronously. Provided that database.query() is part of an asynchronous library, this is what Node.js does: just as before, it takes the query and sends it to the database. But instead of waiting for it to be finished, it makes a mental note that says "When at some point in the future the database server is done and sends the result of the query, then I have to execute the anonymous function that was passed to database.query()."

I am trying the same with a sample code (as I am a newbie and not reached till Node.js DB interactions):

```
[root@example]# cat server8.js
function myfun(noparm , afterend)
{
         for ( var i =0; i < 10; i ++)
                console.log("The valus is " + i);
}

function mynextfn()
{
        console.log("Hello World");
}
function afterend()
{
        console.log("Hello afterend");
}

myfun(0, afterend);
mynextfn();
[root@idc-bldtool01 example]# node server8.js
The valus is 0
The valus is 1
The valus is 2
The valus is 3
The valus is 4
The valus is 5
The valus is 6
The valus is 7
The valus is 8
The valus is 9
Hello World
[root@iexample]#
```

As such I do not see the " concept of event-driven, asynchronous callbacks, by utilizing an event loop" ?

Can anyone please help me in implementing some basic examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You hand the `afterend` function over as a parameter, but you never call it.

Your function `myfun` must be:

```
function myfun(noparm , afterend)
{
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log("The valus is " + i);
  }
  afterend();
}
```

Then that what you expect to will happen ;-)

And: Second thing is that your `myfun` function is completely synchronous. So there is no chance for Node.js to run `mynextfn` before the content of the `myfun` function.

Potentially `afterend` will be run before `myfun`, that depends on timing issues as both do not do any heavy lifting.

Comment: Thanks - please explain what you meant by "myfun function is completely synchronous. So there is no chance for Node.js to run mynextfn before the content of the myfun function."

Comment: What I was trying to say was that myfun doesn't delegate anything to another function that does something in an async way, such as I/O. It's simply a loop running inside your main (single) thread.